# Is this upper bound ok to use when bounding the error between the Riemann sum and its integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

I found this on some class notes, which gives several different estimates of the error term, when going from the Riemann sum to its corresponding Riemann integral:

$$\frac{b-a}{n}[f(b)-f(a)]$$

Does this bound always work?  If so, it is an easy estimate to remember.

EDIT:

The notes show this bound, but only for the difference between the left-endpoint Riemann sum and its integral.  I want to know whether it is applicable to right (and midpoint) sums, too.

Thanks

Comment: What's the context? Note that if $f(a) = f(b)$, the 'error' term is bounded above by 0, for which there are a plethora of counterexamples to.

Comment: Awesome comment, @Nitin.  In the context of a problem that I just worked on, the function is an increasing function.  Does the bound work in this case?  Thanks,

Comment: My concern is that if f(x), the continuous analog of the function in the Riemann sum, were an underestimate throughout the interval, then the bound doesn't work.

Comment: Left approximation:
$$L(f,P_n) = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \; f\left(a + i\,\frac{b-a}{n} \right)$$
Right approximation:
$$U(f,P_n) = \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \; f\left(a + i\,\frac{b-a}{n} \right)$$
Since $L(f,P_n) < \int_a^b f < U(f,P_n)$ for monotone increasing $f$, we have
$$\int_a^b f - L(f,P_n) < U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) = \frac{b-a}{n} [f(b) - f(a)]$$
since the sums telescope.